# How can I change the query used to export price lists?

Tags: export, orocommerce

I need to export a few extra fields when I issue a price list export.

I have this query:

```
select p.sku as 'Product SKU', 1 as Quantity, 'each' as 'Unit Code',  pp.value as Price, 'ARS' as Currency, b.default_title as Brand, c.title as Category from oro_price_product pp inner join oro_product p on p.id = pp.product_id left join oro_brand b on b.id = p.brand_id left join oro_catalog_category c on c.id = p.category_id where price_list_id = 7 order by product_sku
```

Which produces the exact result I need when I run it from the command line, but I'd like to allow the end user to trigger this one when spawning an export job.

I've been looking at the job definitions and reading about the message queue but I can't figure out where to put this code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it from the management console.

Go to System > Entities > Entity Management. Find the entity to which you want to add extra fields and open it. Click on the field you wish to edit and adjust settings in the "Import & Export" section.

Comment: Ok, I think I might have expressed myself wrong. What I want to do is to add a column to the exportation: product brand. I looked at your directions and I believe I should add a new field to the Product Price entity, is that correct? Thanks